# Putting together a Windows batch that runs an executable with a name I only partially know?

Tags: windows, batch-file, autocomplete, cmd, switch-statement

Ultimately, I need to run a setup executable on clients machines that requires an /S switch for a silent install. But I only know the beginning part of the setups name. We keep the latest version in a directory that doesn't change(C:\WFRuntimes), but the setups version is included at the end of the setups file name. So I know it begins with "Runtimes_v"... but it's followed by any number of versions we put out. All versions have a /S switch that allows a silent auto install which needs to be included, too. I understand there's a nifty tab ability for autocomplete, too bad this can't be typed as a command.

By the way, you guys rock!

Comment: I tried using every variation of %% or && I thought there was, but I know I'm close and have the right idea. Probably something extremely simple... always is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hack that might work, or might not, depending on your exact environment:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b Runtimes_v*.exe') do echo %%i /S > temp_runtimes_v.cmd
call temp_runtimes_v.cmd
```

Replace %% with % if using this interactively from the command line (not a batch file).

Edit: This might do the trick without the temp file:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b Runtimes_v*.exe') do cmd /c %%i /S
```

Comment: I'm in Win 7, but the users are anywhere from XP to Win 7. I tried the above command in a Win 7 test environment to no avail :(

Comment: Did you change the %% to % if using directly from the command line?  Other than that, this assumes that only a single Runtimes_v*.exe file will be present in the local directory.

Comment: Paul, can you give me an example of exactly what you mean?

Comment: If you're typing that command directly on the command line, you'd have to replace %% with %.  That is: for /f %i in ('dir /b Runtimes_v*.exe') do cmd /c %i /S

Comment: I think that may have done it. It seems to work on a local directory, but I forgot to mention (I didn't think it would be a problem) the install file is on their server. So I put in a /set p= switch where it asks for the server name etc etc. But problem is, you can't browse UNC paths. So I tried mapping the folder to V:, went to the V: directory, and ran that command. It's causing cmd.exe to crash, so I'm not even sure why it doesn't like it, but it probably has something to do with it being a mapped drive. Ugh. Been at this most of the day. Bout time I go to sleep. Many thanks for your help